# Automorphism group of a cuspidal "elliptic" curve

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, automorphism-group

I have a cuspidal elliptic curve ($\Delta=0$ and $J$-invariant$=0$), $E$ in a field $K$ of characteristic $3$ and I'm trying to show that its automorphism group is $K^*$.
These are my calculations:
$E$ has the form: $$Y^2Z=X^3+a_6Z^3$$
The substitutions preserving this form are:$$X=u^2X+rZ$$ $$Y=u^3Y$$ $$Z=Z$$
Then automorphism of $E$ have: $$a_6(u^6-1)-r^3=0$$
How can I proceed from here?

Comment: How do you get $r=0$?

Comment: you're right, I don't know! If $r$ is not $0$ how can I proceed from that equation? now I will edit my post...

Comment: You should start the same way as in your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698332/automorphism-group-of-elliptic-curves) on automorphisms of an elliptic curves: calculate the composition law on pairs $(u,r)$. What happens when you try to do this? How far can you go?

Comment: the composition law is the same: $(u,r)*(v,s)=(uv,r+u^2s)$ and if $a_6(u^6-1)-r^3=a_6(v^6-1)-s^3=0$ then $a_6[(uv)^6-1]-r^3-u^6s^3=u^6(a_6v^6-s^3)-a_6-r^3=u^6a_6-a_6-r^3=0$ so it's a group. what else can I say? I'm not that good in classifying groups by presentation

Comment: Sorry, I gave you a bad hint in that first comment because I did not think carefully enough before I typed. In any case, you should add what you've tried to your post so that people can give you good help -  see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details. Next, if your calculations are correct, what do you notice about how many possible values of $r$ you have given a value for $u$? You should use the characteristic here in an important way.

Comment: maybe I have an idea: if I pick any $u$ in $K^*$ then $r$ has to solve $a_6u^6-a_6-r^3=0$ so in char 3 $(tu^2-t-r)^3=0$ where $t$ is the cubic root of $a_6$ so there is only one choice for $r$. but I'm not sure it is enough to come to the conclusion...

Answer (score 2):

$\Delta=0$ means that your cubic projective curve is not an elliptic curve. Did you mean the automorphisms of the singular projective curve ? $$E/K:\qquad ZY^2=X^3+aZ^3$$ (singular at the point $[-1:0:1/a]$)

> It is the projective closure of the affine curve $$D:y^2=x^3+a=(x+a)^3$$

With $C:z^2=w$, $x=w-a,y=wz$ we get a birational map $$E\to D\to C \to \Bbb{A}^1, [x:y:1]\to (x,y)\to (x+a,y/(x+a))\to y/(x+a)$$
Which sends $[-1:0:1/a]\to (-1,0)\to 0$.

Any automorphism of $E$ induces a birational map $\Bbb{A^1\to A^1}$, and since $E$ has only one singular point, only the birational maps $\Bbb{A^1\to A^1}$ fixing the image of $[-1:0:1/a]$ induce an automorphism of $E$.

> $Aut(\Bbb{A^1})=Aut(K(z)/K)=PGL_2(K)$,  and the subgroup of $PGL_2(K)$ fixing $0$ is $K^*$.